# Layout weight within scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview, xml-layout

I have a `Scrollview`as my parent container which contains a map, and then some information below the map. It currently looks like the image below.

I'm trying to make it so that the map takes up half of the screen using `layout_weight` but I've had no luck. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            tools:context="com.thevisitapp.visitapp.PlacesActivity"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:id="@+id/map" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/summaryLabel"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:background="@color/gray"
                android:text="summary"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/summary"
                android:layout_below="@+id/summaryLabel"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                tools:text="actual summary"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/contactsLabel"
                android:background="@color/gray"
                android:layout_below="@+id/summary"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:text="contact"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">


        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            tools:context="com.thevisitapp.visitapp.PlacesActivity"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:id="@+id/map" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/summaryLabel"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:background="@color/gray"
            android:text="summary"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/summary"
            android:layout_below="@+id/summaryLabel"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            tools:text="actual summary"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/contactsLabel"
            android:background="@color/gray"
            android:layout_below="@+id/summary"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:text="contact"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I get the same result. It's all squished towards the top like in my previous example

Comment: In your `PlacesActivity` have you handled anything for map ?

Comment: Yes I have. It worked fine when i didn't have a scrollview, everything was nicely spaced, but I know I'm going to run out of room with all the things I'm planning on sticking in, so I switched over to the scrollview and that happened